# store data to MongoDB Collection in millisecond

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

I write application in java to store data from UDP broadcast and store them to MongoDB.
UDP sent in millisecond and it contain about text file separate by coma (about 30 fields).

But i meet the problem as follow (problem show only in 4-5 minutes I run the program).

```
Connect success
Doc inserted
Connect success
Doc inserted
Connect success
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketException: Too many open files}}]
    at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getServer(BaseCluster.java:82)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getServer(DBTCPConnector.java:654)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.access$300(DBTCPConnector.java:39)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.getConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:503)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.get(DBTCPConnector.java:451)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.authenticate(DBTCPConnector.java:624)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer.doAuthenticate(DBApiLayer.java:195)
    at com.mongodb.DB.authenticateCommandHelper(DB.java:765)
    at com.mongodb.DB.authenticate(DB.java:721)
    at UdpGPSListener.main(UdpGPSListener.java:108)
```

and below is my code in Java :

```
            DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(2020);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[2048];
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        String dtCollection = new String(receivePacket.getData(), "UTF8");
        String[] arrCollection = dtCollection.split(",");
        String dtField = "UnitTime,Ab1,ab2,ab3,ab4,ab5,ab6,ab7,cc1,cc2,cc3,cc4,cc5,cc6,cc7,cc8,cc9,cc9,cc10,m01,m02,m03,m04,m05,m06,m07";
        String[] arrField = dtField.split(",");
        String gbCollection="";
        for (int m=0; m<arrCollection.length; m++) {
            gbCollection+=arrField[m] + "=" +arrCollection[m] +",";
        }
            try {
                MongoClient mClient = new MongoClient();
                //MongoClient mClient = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);
                DB db = mClient.getDB("mms");
                        System.out.println("Connect success");
                boolean auth = db.authenticate("user1", "passw0rd".toCharArray());
                DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("tgps");
                BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject(arrField[0], arrCollection[0]).
                    append(arrField[1], arrCollection[1]).
                    append(arrField[2], arrCollection[2]).
                    append(arrField[3], arrCollection[3]).
                    append(arrField[4], arrCollection[4]).
                    append(arrField[5], arrCollection[5]).
                    append(arrField[6], arrCollection[6]).
                    append(arrField[7], arrCollection[7]).
                    append(arrField[8], arrCollection[8]).
                    append(arrField[9], arrCollection[9]).
                    append(arrField[10], arrCollection[10]).
                    append(arrField[11], arrCollection[11]).
                    append(arrField[12], arrCollection[12]).
                    append(arrField[13], arrCollection[13]).
                    append(arrField[14], arrCollection[14]).
                    append(arrField[15], arrCollection[15]).
                    append(arrField[16], arrCollection[16]).
                    append(arrField[17], arrCollection[17]).
                    append(arrField[18], arrCollection[18]).
                    append(arrField[19], arrCollection[19]).
                    append(arrField[20], arrCollection[20]).
                    append(arrField[21], arrCollection[21]).
                    append(arrField[22], arrCollection[22]).
                    append(arrField[23], arrCollection[23]).
                    append(arrField[24], arrCollection[24]).
                    append(arrField[25], new Date());
                coll.insert(doc);
                System.out.println("Doc inserted");
            } catch(UnknownHostException  e) {
                    System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
            } catch(MongoException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by

> > UDP sent in millisecond

you mean that an update may occur every millisecond.

Anyway you encounter this problem:

> > java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

I also assume that you receive your events in some kind of a loop.

In that case, this may be your problem:

`MongoClient mClient = new MongoClient();`

You should init `MongoClient` only once before start listening to events, otherwise a connection is opened and never closed for every event you consume.

This should also go for obtaining db, authenticating and getting collection. i.e

```
 MongoClient mClient = new MongoClient();
 //MongoClient mClient = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);
 DB db = mClient.getDB("mms");
 System.out.println("Connect success");
 boolean auth = db.authenticate("user1", "passw0rd".toCharArray());
 DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("tgps");
```

All these should happen only **once** before you start receiving events.

Comment: Thanks for your Advice Orid, that's true. I finally add MongoClient.Close than problem is gone.